# Making an eraser in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've started to make a painting program in WPF using an inkpresenter, but I'm starting to doubt the approach. I am implementing the eraser and realise if I delete parts of the strokes the precision will be really bad. I do not want to delete a whole part of the stroke if someone just wants to delete one pixel of a stroke with width 10.

Do I keep the inkPresenter and just render to a writeablebitmap whenever I need pixels, and then continue with a new inkPresenter on top of that bitmap? Or is there a better approach to making a painting program in wpf? Should I forget about wpf and go back to gdi+ ? I'm liking the performance but not having direct access to pixels is really bugging me.

Comment: InkPresenter fundamentally works with vector based graphics - to try to make it work like a raster graphics program is probably not the best approach.  You're trying to make something like Photoshop when your tools are more suited to work like Illustrator, if you follow my meaning.  This is not to say that it cannot be done, but the task of making vectors feel like pixels is not a trivial one.  If you like the rendering of the inkpresenter you might consider using it for the current stroke only, and rasterizing/compositing the result to an underlying bitmap once committed.

Comment: Yes, rendering to an underlying bitmap and just using the inkpresenter while drawing was what I was thinking of doing, but maybe there is an alternative to using the inkpresenter altogether ?

Comment: The inkpresenter's function here would be to relieve you of the need to write a brush rendering engine.  The alternative would be to write your own rendering engine, I suppose.

Comment: To your attention i want to introduce an [app](http://fantasia.nokola.com/). And here's [source](http://nokola.com/blog/post/2010/07/22/Fantasia-Lite-New-Silverlight-Painting-Tool.aspx). Have a look at this blog, it has many nice tricks and articles about what you want.